# How can I default to front-facing camera when using strictly the HTML5 input field with video on iOS and Android?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, video

When using the `<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camcorder">` tag in a web page on a mobile browser, Mobile Safari & Chrome on Android correctly prompt to take or upload video.

This is unrelated to `getUserMedia`, which doesn't work on Safari on iOS anyhow. See more about the current state of video capture in a mobile browser here: https://plus.google.com/+ThomasQuintana/posts/SuFgtvCyQxv

Is there a way to default the Take Video popup action in iOS or Android to the front-facing camera?

Comment: You should consider using just `capture` (boolean) instead of `capture="camcorder"` (string) as [in the last several spec revisions](https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot default the action sheet to record from the front-facing camera by default.

On iOS, this would require the use of the constant `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront` somewhere when initializing the `UIImagePickerController`. Since this constant does not appear anywhere in the WebKit codebase, it must be unsupported.